# HeaderStyle not found in type DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to center my Columns in my DataGrid by using:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvMain" Margin="10,438,10,10" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I keep getting the error that is labeled in the title whenever using this XAML. I have tried creating this as a Style and using a Namespace, but that returned the same error as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvMain" Margin="10,438,10,10" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You are missing the `<DataGridTextColumn>` tag

Comment: That got rid of the error, but my original code still didn't work. I looked a bit further and found CoulumnHeaderStyle and that worked. I'll post the update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvMain" Margin="10,438,10,10" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is what worked for me.